# on("show", function()) doesn't work in FF extension

Tags: javascript, firefox-addon

I have FF extension where on showing panel event focus automatically should be on text input field `parameter`. I am using `on("show", function())` (in `scrip.js`) for that, but no matter what I insert into this function it doesn't work.

Any suggestions?

**main.js:**

```
var panel = panels.Panel({
    contentURL: self.data.url("index.html"),
    contentScriptFile: self.data.url("script.js"),
    onHide: handleHide,
    width: 250,
    height: 200
});

function handleChange(state) {
    if (state.checked) {
        panel.show({
            position: button
        });
    }
}
```

**script.js:**

```
self.port.on("show", function onShow() {
    document.getElementById("parameter").focus();
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`show` is an event, it is emitted to the `panel.on("eventname")` callbacks. The `port` is for messaging between the addon context and the panel context.

I.e. `panel.port.on(...)` is not the same as `panel.on(...)`.

And it's not available in the panel context. Maybe you can use pageshow/pagehide dom events for that purpose, alternatively you could reflect the event from your addon to the panel through the port.

Comment: Thank you!
I added following code into the `main.js` and it works now:

`panel.on("show", function() {
        panel.port.emit("show");
  });`

Answer (score 1):

Adding following code into `main.js` helped:

```
panel.on("show", function() { 
    panel.port.emit("show");
});
```